# Android studio is not working, it it opening in the taskbar, but it is showing a white screen and I can not use it

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio

I have tried a few things including changing JDK_HOME to the current JDK, removing all jdk and installing jdk8, and reinstalling android studio, but the same issue persists.

I have used the program before and it was working a few days ago

Answer (score 1):

(After wasting half a day on it, finally, I got it running)

I am running it on Windows 8.1. Also, I had JDK 1.7.0_13.

I tried the following:

Open Start menu > Computer > System Properties > Advanced System Properties In the Advanced tab > Environment Variables
Add new system variable JAVA_HOME that points to JDK folder, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13
Just to be on the safer side, also add new system variable JDK_HOME that points to JDK folder, for example, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13
Append new PATH in system variable that points to JDK folder, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13
But still it didn't work. Then it struck me that might be, my Java version is old. I downloaded the latest version from here.

I uninstalled JDK 1.7.0_13 and installed version 8 i.e. JDK 1.8.0_131.

Now do all the above steps but, replace the path with C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\ OR whichever your latest version is.

Success!! Now it works.